# Using Laravel's ORM - what's the difference between the longhand and the shorthand?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

For instance:

`return Product::first()->BaseProduct->Products`

works, whereas

`return Product::first()->BaseProduct()->Products()`

does not, and I get a `BadMethodCallException`.

I understand that there's a notable difference, then, between those two lines, but what is difference, and how does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that BaseProduct() and Products() are both relationships in your models? Calling Products() won't return eloquent objects, it'll return a hasMany or belongsToMany (children of Relation) object.

Calling Products instead of Products() triggers a magic get method. This magic get calls the getResults() method on the Relation object. This way you actually get back a collection of the Product models. This is typically the way that you should work with relationships.

In other words:

`BaseProduct::first()->Products == BaseProduct::first()->Products()->getResults()`

I suggest that you have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php)